# ORACLE "ANY" Keyword in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

The following query works well in Oracle, but not in SQL SERVER. I know "ANY", keyword in SQL SERVER developed for some other purpose, but I Wanna know is there any similar keyword in SQL SERVER FOR doing this
   In the following query fisrtname, lastname, middlename are columns in Person table

```
SELECT * FROM Person WHERE 'Somename' = ANY(firstname, lastname,middlename)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between in and any operators in sql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3699356/difference-between-in-and-any-operators-in-sql)

Comment: Or also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298550/oracle-any-vs-in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equivalent is

```
SELECT * FROM Person WHERE 'Somename' IN (firstname, lastname, middlename)
```

Comment: i never tried to put column names in the IN condition i'm just checking it and you posted the answer :P

Comment: I'm not sure, but does the optimizer really index the query correctly when using IN like this?

Comment: ya, this works cool, how can I do this for checking not null?

Comment: @njr Queries aren't indexed - tables are indexed. The optimizer won't treat this any differently to an expanded OR statement.

Comment: @Surendhar I don't understand. The `IN` statement compares values. If you want to check a value is not null use `IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: @TimRogers: Ya, but how to use IS NOT NULL with "IN" condition?

Comment: @Surendhar Sorry, I still don't understand your question. Do you mean you want to check if `firstname`, `lastname`, or `middlename` are null? You don't need to because you are checking if any of them matches a value, and they are not going to match a value if they are null.

Comment: @Timrogers: say I wanna select rows where firstname or lastname or middle name is not null. Writing query using OR condition is trivial one, but just wanna know is there any possibility to write query using ANY keyword

Answer (score 0):

Can you not simply do:

```
SELECT * FROM Person
WHERE
     firstname = 'Somename'
  OR lastname = 'Somename'
  OR middlename= 'Somename'
```

There are other possibilities but in most cases they will not let the optimizer make such good use of the indexes e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM Person
WHERE
     ('---' + firstname + '---' + lastname + '---' + middlename + '---')
     LIKE '%---Somename---%'
```

Comment: The 2nd solution looks good, but what if I am checking for not null.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a way to check multiple columns other than writing something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Person WHERE 
firstname = 'Somename' 
OR lastname = 'Somename' 
OR middlename = 'somename'
```

Comment: This is obvious, but I want to know is there any similar keyword in SQL Server. In this case its only 3 columns, what if there are ten columns, and I want to check for some other value, then I don't want to change the value again and again in all places.