# PostgreSQL - IN vs ANY

Tags: postgresql, operation, any, sql-in

I have tried both:

1. *smthng **`= ANY`** `(select id from exmplTable)`*
2. *smthng **`IN`** `(select id from exmplTable)`*

and I am getting the same results for my data.

Is there any difference for the two expressions?

Comment: From the [docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-subquery.html): *`SOME` is a synonym for `ANY`. `IN` is equivalent to `= ANY`.*

Comment: Have a look, its explained here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparisons.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between in and any operators in sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3699356/difference-between-in-and-any-operators-in-sql)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

No, in these variants are same:

You can see - the execution plans are same too:

```
postgres=# explain select * from foo1 where id in (select id from foo2);
┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                            QUERY PLAN                            │
╞══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│ Hash Semi Join  (cost=3.25..21.99 rows=100 width=4)              │
│   Hash Cond: (foo1.id = foo2.id)                                 │
│   ->  Seq Scan on foo1  (cost=0.00..15.00 rows=1000 width=4)     │
│   ->  Hash  (cost=2.00..2.00 rows=100 width=4)                   │
│         ->  Seq Scan on foo2  (cost=0.00..2.00 rows=100 width=4) │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
(5 rows)

postgres=# explain select * from foo1 where id = any (select id from foo2);
┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                            QUERY PLAN                            │
╞══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│ Hash Semi Join  (cost=3.25..21.99 rows=100 width=4)              │
│   Hash Cond: (foo1.id = foo2.id)                                 │
│   ->  Seq Scan on foo1  (cost=0.00..15.00 rows=1000 width=4)     │
│   ->  Hash  (cost=2.00..2.00 rows=100 width=4)                   │
│         ->  Seq Scan on foo2  (cost=0.00..2.00 rows=100 width=4) │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
(5 rows)
```

Comment: Note that while this is true for the form taking a *set*, there is a second form for each `IN ()` and `= ANY()` and those are not completely equivalent. Consider: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34627688/939860 and http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/125413/3684

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: =ANY(ARRAY) is different creature .. although the syntax is same

Answer (score 22):

This may be an edge case but:

```
select * from myTable where id IN ()
```

will produce: ERROR: syntax error at or near ")"

but

```
select * from myTable where id = ANY('{}');
```

Will return an empty result set

Comment: This is a good thing to know when querying with dynamic set of data (Pg/PLSQL, application programing, etc..)

Comment: This is different operator. There is difference between `= ANY ( subquery )` and `= ANY ( array )`. ` = ANY( '{}' )` is example of usage of array.

Answer (score 3):

**Note:** verified and working

**Create Table**: user

```
CREATE TABLE user (
  id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  username VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
  skills VARCHAR[50]
);
```

Insert data

```
insert into user (username, skills) values ('user1', '{java, python}');
insert into user (username, skills) values ('user2', '{python}');
insert into user (username) values ('user3');
```

In the above table user when we search for 'python' in column skills, then it will return 2 rows. As it matches python in the first 2 rows.

```
SELECT * FROM user where  'python' = ANY (skills);
```

output

```
 1 | user1 | {java, python}
 2 | user2 | {python}
```