# How to use Ecto.Adapters.SQL.query with Arrays?

Tags: sql, elixir, ecto

I'm trying to use `Ecto.Adapters.SQL.query`, it works fine, but not for arrays. For example this statement fails:

```
Ecto.Adapters.SQL.query Repo, "SELECT p.* FROM posts p WHERE p.title in ($1)", 
  [["title1", "title2"]]
```

The error:

```
** (ArgumentError) Postgrex expected a binary that can be encoded/cast to
type "text", got ["title1", "title2"]. Please make sure the value you are
passing matches the definition in your table or in your query or convert
the value accordingly.
```

**UPDATE**

There's no easy way to do it, but it is not a limitation of Ecto, it is a **limitation of SQL databases / PostgreSQL**, [more details and workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178479/preparedstatement-in-clause-alternatives).

It's hard to believe that in 2016 SQL databases still laking such a basic feature...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer to this question is pretty much the same from your previous question. Just use the `in` syntax from [here](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.API.html#in/2).

**Update**

To run a raw sql query for your example, you can use the following:

```
Ecto.Adapters.SQL.query(MyApp.Repo, "SELECT p.* FROM POSTS p WHERE p.TITLE IN ($1, $2)", ["title1", "title2"])
```

Comment: Thanks, yes it's possible to do with Query DSL, but still - the ability to execute raw SQL seems to be quite fundamental to the SQL library. I'd like to see the answer - how to do it.

Comment: But how to render the result into the view, i.e. how to make use of `Ecto.Adapters.SQL.query(MyApp.Repo,..`? How to pass the result to teh view? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using Postgres you can also use [ANY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-comparisons.html#AEN20944)

```
Ecto.Adapters.SQL.query(
  Repo,
  "SELECT p.* FROM posts p WHERE p.title = ANY($1)", 
  [["title1", "title2"]]
)
```

And Postgres produces the [same query plan for In vs Any](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30263671/postgresql-in-vs-any)