# How to use the result from subquery as an input parameter into another subquery using IN() or ANY()

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

How to fetch a list of distinct IDs using one query and then feed this list as an input parameter for IN() or ANY() of another query in Postgres.

```
(SELECT DISTINCT id FROM inventory WHERE supplier_id = 37) AS idlist  
(SELECT SUM(item_price) FROM transaction WHERE person_id IN (idlist)) AS output
```

NOTE: Specifically, I don't want to use subquery as a constraint in WHERE clause as proposed in some of the answers below. And I don't want to use nested subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use your SELECT DISTINCT .... query as a sub-query within the second query's IN() criteria.

That is:

```
SELECT SUM(item_price) 
FROM transaction 
WHERE person_id 
IN 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT id 
    FROM inventory 
    WHERE supplier_id = 37
)
```

And, in this sort of instance, you don't specifically need the DISTINCT keyword in that sub-query

Comment: This is not the answer to my question. My question specifically asked for using the result of a query in  IN or ANY of another subquery, and not for using subquery as a constraint in WHERE clause.

Comment: Hey @Jimski - your question doesn't say anything in particular about "ANY".  I will admit, the way the question is set out simply looks to me like someone who didn't understand the use of "IN" in SQL syntax

Comment: This old-ish question is probably still relevant, in terms of describing the usage of both IN and ANY with a sub-query (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3699356/difference-between-in-and-any-operators-in-sql) .... essentially, the same principal still applies.  You may need to elaborate a bit more on your particular use-case / business-case if you feel these answers are not satisfying your requirement

Comment: The old-ish question is not relevant. My question is not about the difference between IN and ANY but about passing a result form subquery into IN or ANY of another subquery.

Comment: I guess you could use string_agg() to build an array string that could be passed to ANY(), but if you're specifying individual values to IN() it doesn't work in quite the same - you can't just pass a single string of comma-delimited values to IN().  To be honest, without still understanding the specific use-case of what you're doing, it's hard to understand exactly why using the initial query as a sub-query is not an option.  Anyhow, either way, I think doing a string_agg() and passing that to ANY() is your best option.

Comment: Why do you say that I can't pass a comma delimited string to IN()??? I'm doing it all the time when string is specified explicitly and it works just fine.

Comment: Hey @Jimski.  I'll admit I'm not as familiar with postgresql as other RDBMS - are you saying that postgresql will return results (where an "id" value is either a, b or c) if have SELECT * from table WHERE id IN ('a,b,c') ... rather than IN ('a','b','c')?  If that is actually the case then string_agg() will be your likely solution in both cases.  (As a comparison, if the query in SQL Server was ... IN ('a,b,c'), then the "id" value would have to actually be "a,b,c" (as opposed to one of either a, b or c).  Does that all make sense?